# Why Are Features of XAML Missing From the Phone SDK?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

It seems that various parts of XAML are not supported on the phone that are otherwise supported on the desktop. I created a question on this yesterday where-by `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid` was not included in the XAML on the phone SDK.

Why is the XAML different and certain features missing?

As a side not it becomes a problem when you're trying to search Google for documentation, or help, on a topic, or how to achieve a solution from an XAML phone SDK problem it becomes difficult because you get results for XAML desktop development, which are unsupported on the phone. It's also difficult to search Microsoft Docs because they don't tell you what's included or not included on the Phone SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the differences you will need to check out MSDN articles such as

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

This goes into detail about the limitations of sharing the UI

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714088%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

However, to answer your question:

> XAML on Windows Phone 8 and XAML on Windows 8 is not binary
>   compatible. As stated earlier, the controls you use to build your UI
>   on each platform are similar. They are similar in name, behavior, and
>   the programming interfaces, or syntax, they expose. However, they are
>   implemented specifically for each platform.
>
> Namespace prefixes are different in XAML for Windows Phone 8 and XAML
>   for Windows 8. This is illustrated by looking at the namespaces
>   included in a basic page when you create it from scratch.